# How to divide the integer value

Tags: vb.net, integer-division

I want to perform integer division in VB.NET, i.e. only keep the whole part of division result.

```
Dim a, b, c as int32
a = 3500
b = 1200
c = a/b
```

This example outputs `3`.

How do I make it return `2` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual calculation: `3500/1200 = 2.916`

You have to use `Math.Floor` method to roundup the value to `2` as below -

```
c = Math.Floor(a/b)
```

More information is available on MSDN - [Math.Floor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh.aspx)

Comment: This is wrong if negative numbers are involved (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division) you have to round towards zero.

Answer (score 17):

Since this is Visual Basic you have 2 division [operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [`/`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is for Standard division and [`\`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which is used for integer division, which returns the "*integer quotient of the two operands, with the remainder discarded*" which sounds like what you want.

results:

```
a/b = 3
a\b = 2
```

Comment: Much better than using a `Math.Floor`, since we are talking VB.NET here.

Comment: +1 for nice feature. But using `/` or `\\` wont be much readable and wont show intention of rounding up the values in the calculation.

Comment: @MarkHall - I have learned C# & VB.NET w/out prior knowledge to VB6. And I am new to VB.NET so this feature is a surprise for me :)

Comment: @ParagMeshram It is one I constantly bump my head against trying to remember which is which. I do agree that having a nicely named function is clearer :). Commenting is your friend